# Exceptions in jsp

Tags: jsp, session, exception

My question is regarding exceptions. Is it really bad if the program throws an exception even if i handle it?? 
I am working on a jsp project, where i have set the username of a user as a session variable, which i access on every page, like this `session.getAttribute("username")` to convert it into a string i use `.toString()` function to convert it into string which i then use in my code for further processing.

So, if the user hasn't authenticated himself at the login page and tries to access some page such as `view-forums.jsp` (one of the page names in my project) directly from the url then the`session.getAttribute("username").toString()` throws a null pointer exception, for which I have an error page, which looks like this

```
<%@page  isErrorPage="true"%>
<%@include file="classes/template.jsp"%>
<%
    session.invalidate();
    Template objTemplate=new Template();
    String Data="<div id=text>ERROR!!!!!!!!!! Page Not Found<br>Please Sign in Again</div>";
    out.println(objTemplate.genPage(Data,false));
%>`
```

So, whenever there is any exception my webapp gets redirected to this error page. So, in a way I am using exceptions to make secure login to my website. Is this is a bad way to do so?? If yes then can someone please explain?
Thanks for your any help in advance.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is bad. Scriptlets were acceptable technology over a decade ago. Their time has come and gone.

New code should be using model view controller (MVC). The idea is to have your logic in a servlet (or a class called from a servlet) and have it forward to a JSP for display purposes only.

Having any scriptlets in a JSP isn't good. Having scriptlets with logic in a JSP is even worse.

Why not put all that code in a servlet?

Comment: Thanks :) I read a few things about MVC and advantages of servlet over jsp, and I got your point. Thank you so much.. :) I'll try and implement it. But, is this way of securing like I mentioned, of throwing exception if the user is not validated and redirecting to an error page. Why is it bad? Like whats happening behind that makes it bad? @Jeanne Boyarsky

Comment: It's bad because it is not the way people are used to doing things. If someone new takes over that code, he/she has a lot of work to determine if it is working properly.